# Zombie.js pressButton Long Callback Delay

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, mocha.js, zombie.js

I've been trying to figure this out by using a bunch of console.logs and still can't figure out why these load times are so long.

So I have the following code in my `beforeEach` in my Mocha unit test file.

```
browser.fill('email', 'test1@test.com');
browser.fill('password', 'testtest');
browser.pressButton('Login').then(function () {
    console.log("#100 - "+ new Date().getTime());
    done();
});
```

Pressing the button in this case will have a few redirects then finally display a dashboard page. At the bottom of that html file I have the following code.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        console.log("#200 - "+ new Date().getTime());
    });
</script>
```

So after running the tests if I take the value after `#100` **minus** the value after `#200` it's always about 5000-6000. Because `#200` always gets printed before `#100` by like 5-6 seconds.

I don't understand why after loading the page it takes an additional 5-6 seconds about for Zombie.js to call that callback function.

Does Zombie.js have some wait or delay that I'm missing after loading the page? What else could be causing this 5-6 second delay between the page loading and Zombie.js calling that callback function?

**EDIT** I now have this same problem but with like a 50000ms. And that really adds up super quickly over all of my tests. I still can't figure out why this is happening.

**EDIT 2**

If I add `browser.debug()` to my test it prints the following at the very end. It also prints a lot of other stuff but that happens overall pretty quickly. I think the following might be the problem. Just not sure why it's doing that or how to fix it.

```
zombie Fired setInterval every 5000ms +11ms
zombie Fired setInterval every 5000ms +5s
zombie Fired setInterval every 5000ms +5s
zombie Fired setInterval every 5000ms +5s
zombie Fired setInterval every 5000ms +5s
zombie Fired setInterval every 5000ms +5s
zombie Fired setInterval every 5000ms +5s
zombie Fired setInterval every 5000ms +5s
zombie Fired setInterval every 5000ms +5s
zombie Fired setInterval every 5000ms +5s
zombie Fired setInterval every 5000ms +5s
```

What is causing all of the `zombie Fired setInterval every 5000ms` and how do I fix it to make it not take 55000ms+?

**EDIT 3**

I also added the following code at the beginning of the unit test.

```
browser.addListener("setInterval",function (a,b) {
    console.log("a: "+a);
    console.log("b: "+b);
});
```

After printing each `zombie Fired setInterval every 5000ms +5s` it also prints the following because of that listener.

```
a: function (){var b,c,d;if(b=window.location.href,b!==h){try{d=JSON.stringify({action:"ping",sid:a.utils.getSessionID(),muid:a.utils.getMerchantID(),referrer:h,url:b,title:document.title}),e.contentWindow.postMessage(d,"*")}catch(f){c=f}return h=b}}
b: 5000
```

`a` and `b` are the same after each one of those 11 `zombie Fired setInterval every 5000ms`. It doesn't change at all between those 11 times.

I thought that function would help in someway but I still don't understand why this is happening or how to fix it at all.

Answer (score 2):

Zombie loads all resources and processes all events before triggering the callback. Instead of using **pressButton**, try submitting the form directly and using **wait** with a terminator callback which will be called after each event. This should show you what's causing the delay:

```
browser.document.forms[0].submit();
browser.wait(function(){
   //called after each event
}, function() {
   //all events processed
});
```

From the API docs:

> **browser.wait(callback)**
>
> **browser.wait(terminator, callback)**
>
> Process all events in the queue and calls the callback when done.
>
> You can use the **second** form to pass control before processing all
>   events. The terminator can be a number, in which case that many events
>   are processed. It can be a **function**, which is called after each event;
>   processing stops when the function returns the value false.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply. Didn't see this until now. How exactly would I detect changes after each event? I've ran `console.log(browser.html());` if the MS difference between each event is > than a certain amount. But I can't find any changes between any of those. So how would I figure out what is taking so long between events? I currently have this unit test that is taking well over a minute and I can't figure out why. In the past it took about 7 seconds or so. Now it's taking over 8x that. And I can't find any changes in my code that would cause that.